# How can i test downloading excel file with jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am new to testing react components with jest and enzyme. I have this example

```
generateExcelFile = () => {
        const {actions, state} = this.props;
        const dateFrom = state.getIn(['config', 'marketingQuestionReport', 'dateFrom']);
        const dateTo = state.getIn(['config', 'marketingQuestionReport', 'dateTo']);

        this.setState({isLoading: true, isLoadingFinished: false});
        fetch(`${env.MARKETING_QUESTION_REPORT}?dateFrom=${dateFrom}&dateTo=${dateTo}`)
            .then((resp) => resp.blob())
            .then((blob) => {
                if (typeof window.navigator.msSaveBlob !== 'undefined') {
                    window.navigator.msSaveBlob(
                        blob,
                        `Marketing Question Report from ${dateFrom} to ${dateTo}.xlsx`
                    );
                }

                const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                const tempLink = document.createElement('a');
                tempLink.style.display = 'none';
                tempLink.href = url;
                tempLink.setAttribute(
                    'download',
                    `Marketing Question Report from ${dateFrom} to ${dateTo}.xlsx`
                );

                if (typeof tempLink.download === 'undefined') {
                    tempLink.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
                }

                document.body.appendChild(tempLink);
                tempLink.click();
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);

                toastr.success('Sucessfully generated marketing question report');
                this.setState({isLoading: false, isLoadingFinished: true});
                actions.clearMarketingQuestionReportDates();
            })
            .catch(() =>
                toastr.error('An error occurred while generating marketing question report')
            );
    };
```

I am struck on .then part i don't know how to test after that the whole fetch call

What i have sofar

```
    describe('<MarketingQuestionReportPage />', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        const fecthSpy = jest.spyOn(window, 'fetch').mockReturnValue(() =>
            Promise.resolve({
                blob: () =>
                    Promise.resolve({
                        size: 6682,
                        type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
                    }),
            })
        );
    });


    test('generateExcelFile', () => {
        const props = {
            state: fromJS({
                config: {
                    marketingQuestionReport: {
                        dateFrom: '2019-01-01',
                        dateTo: '2021-03-21',
                    },
                },
            }),
            actions: {
                clearMarketingQuestionReportDates: jest.fn(),
            },
        };
        const tree = shallowSetup(props);
        tree.instance().generateExcelFile();
        tree.fecthSpy.toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

i maked a instance of my component - i got prepaired the needed props for that call to work and i am sending them to my instance.After that i call my method - `generateExcelFile();`

On my coverage everything is freen except the fetch call. I don't know how to fix this. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a `spy` of `fetch` before rendering the component with [jest.spyOn(object, methodName)](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname):

```
test('generateExcelFile', () => {
    const fetchSpy = jest.spyOn(window, "fetch").mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve({
      blob: () =>
        Promise.resolve({
          size: 6682,
          type:
            "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
        }),
      })
    );
    //...
    const tree = shallowSetup(props);
    tree.instance().generateExcelFile();
    expect(fetchSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

In your test you can check if `fecthSpy` have been called

Comment: Thank you for your response. But will on coverage i don't get the lines covered. I edited my question with your suggested answer - please take a look

Comment: I tried also adding just beforeEach at my describe, i don't call nothing explicit in my generateExcelFile test but still i have red coverage on my npm run test

Comment: @sdsd I think you are getting an error in some part, is the catch block coverage?

Comment: @sdsd I updated my answer, I fixed mockReturnValue, it should return a Promise, not a function, also to check if the fetch have been called you need to use expect. I tested and it worked, if it didn't work for you, check other part of your code because it is possible you are getting an error from there.

Comment: Thank you very much.Now the coverage increase.I will accept your answer.It remains only this line un coveraged -   const tempLink = document.createElement('a'); and if (typeof tempLink.download === 'undefined') {
     tempLink.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    } DO YOU KNOW MAYNE HOW WE CAN COVERAGE THAT WITH YOUR MOCK ?

Comment: Yes, the reason is jsdom doesn't support createObjectURL, in this case you can mock it, window.URL["createObjectURL"] = jest.fn(()=> "fake value"), the same with revokeObjectURL, and later you can check if window.URL.createObjectURL have been called

Comment: Thank you very muchj